Efficiency of thermal (rankine) power plants based on ambient temperature?
so I'm preparing for an interview and this is a common question that they always ask,
Say there are two power plants working on ideal rankine cycle
One in Alaska (low ambient temperature) and one in Miami(relatively high ambient temperature), the question is

which one would produce more mork?


Which one would be more efficient?

So, obviously my first thought is that one in Alaska should be more efficient and work producing because of low inlet temperature hence low heat rejection.
But there next question becomes

Then why not just shift every plant there?

And now I'm stuck can you please help?

Let's just take the temperature in Alaska as  0 $^0$C (273 K) and in Miami 30 $^0$C (303 K). Let the hot reservoir be 400 $^0$C. For simplicity let's use the Carnot cycle efficiency instead of the ideal Rankine Cycle (which is usually described in terms of enthalpy). The Carnot efficiency is
$$\eta=1-\frac{T_C}{T_H}$$.
Using the Carnot efficiency the maximum theoretical efficiency in Alaska would be 59% and in Miami 55%. The theoretical amount of work would be the same for both.
Do you think it worthwhile to relocate all power plants to Alaska and create the infrastructure needed to distribute the power?
Hope this helps.
